# Is it possible to access a html outside of webapp?

Tags: html, tomcat

I have a process to generate html file dynamically, but i dont want to place those html files under the webapp, because if the project are re-deployed, I have to deal with the existing html files(copy out and copy in).

So I'm just wondering if I can place the html files outside of the webapp.
If not, is there any other proper way to meet the requriement?

I'm using tomcat.

Appropriate your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create below dir if not exist:
   ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost
2. Create a xml file "article.xml", place the xml under the above path as follows.
   ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost/article.xml
3. Add below content to the xml.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Context path="/article" docBase="C:/apps/blog/article" debug="0" 
> reloadable="true" privileged="true">
> </Context>
> ```

4. Start tomcat.
5. If there's aa.html under the C:/apps/blog/article, use http://localhost:8080/article/aa.html to access the html.

NOTE:
1. Tomcat will take the xml as an web application, and load the resource configed in the xml.
2. No need to create WEB-INF and META-INF for the external folder(C:/apps/blog/article here).

Comment: see Virtual webapp in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html